# Android, Java for loop stops unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, database, for-loop

I am making an app, that saves school timetable. The TimetableFragment manages the input.
TimetableFragment.onPause():

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    db.insertTimetable();
}
```

It calls a database method, thar inputs values to database.
The problematic code is here:

```
getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE_SPECIALS, null, null);
    for(int q = 0;q<6;q++){
        ContentValues specials = new ContentValues();
        boolean b = Timetable.get().getDay(q).hasSpecialTimetable();
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(b)+ " " + String.valueOf(q));
        int dura = Timetable.get().getDay(q).getSpecialDuration();
        int num = Timetable.get().getDay(q).getLessonNumber();
        int[] br = Timetable.get().getDay(q).getSpecialBreaks();
        if (b) {
            if(br!=null) {
                int len = br.length;
                for(int i = 0;q<len;q++){
                    specials.put("p"+String.valueOf(i+1), br[i]);
                }
            }

            specials.put("hasSpec", b);
            specials.put("lNum", num);
            specials.put("lDura", dura);
        }
        getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_SPECIALS, null, specials);
    }
```

As you can see, I log the "q" value to notice the issue (information is not being saved correctly);
There my log:

- 03-19 19:00:12.938  24797-24797/? D/DatabaseHelper﹕ false 0
- 03-1919:00:12.939  24797-24797/? D/DatabaseHelper﹕ false 1
- 03-19 19:00:12.940  24797-24797/? D/DatabaseHelper﹕ true 2

As you can see, it does the third loop and then does nothing.
It is seen in a program - i have the timetables only for Monday, Tuesday and Wenesday.

So....what to do? I have no idea. Please, help.

Comment: `for(int i = 0;q<len;q++){` please check variable "i" or "q".

Answer (score 2):

Your inner for-loop is wrong:

```
for(int i = 0;q<len;q++){
```

Should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
```

You are incrementing `q` by mistake.